# Open a terminal in Python script and execute terminal commands in that newly opened terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, macos

I need to create a Python script to open a terminal window in Mac/Linux and need to execute the following commands in terminal from Python script.

1. Open terminal
2. Execute the command sudo openpyn --init""
3. It will prompt for us to enter password and user name - Pass it from Python script

Tried with below but it is not working,Any idea or recommendations please.Will be of great help.

```
from openpyn import openpyn
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.call(["sudo openpyn --init"], shell=True)
os.system("sudo openpyn --init")
```

But it is not giving any results or not working as expected.

Comment: Beware, by default `sudo` reads a password from /dev/tty because a password has no reason to come from another program...

Comment: You didn't start a Terminal, you started a shell. Maybe `os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello"'""")`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks a lot !! os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo hello"'""") added this line terminal window is popping up, But when i try to execute the terminal commands like os.sysstem("""ls -l""") no results are coming any idea how we can do this?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I was thinking if we can spawn a terminal window and execute the commands from PYTHON ,will it be possible to pass credentials like user name and password from there?

Comment: You've done exactly the same thing again. You haven't started a Terminal, you just are running `ls` without a Terminal.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can you post it as answer.Please.Got it,thanks.

Comment: If you want to run `ls -l` in a Terminal, you need to do `os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "ls -l"'""")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't fully understand the wording of your question, but if you want to pop up a Terminal and run:

```
ls -l
```

in that Terminal, you can do:

```
import os
os.system("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "ls -l"'""")
```

Comment: This is specific to Mac. If you need something similar on Linux, try `xterm -e 'ls -l' &` or whichever terminal application you want to spawn.

Comment: @MarkSetchall One thing if you can answer this it would be great, What if i want to execute multiple terminal commands in the same terminal window?

Comment: Change `ls -l` to `date; ls -l; pwd`